# C99 define values passed as literal initializer values to structure, failing as non-const

Tags: c, struct, constants

In the (old) Linux source code (written in C89), a `#define` occurs that is used as a literal in the initialization of a structure (`ide_pci_device_s`) using the standard C89 struct literal initializer syntax, however, when I compile with a compiler that supports C99, I get the error `initializer element is not constant`, below is a sample of the code I am working with which throws the error.

```
#define ON_BOARD 1

#define PCI_VENDOR_ID_INTEL     0x8086
#define PCI_DEVICE_ID_INTEL_82371FB_0   0x122e

#define DEVID_PIIXa     ((ide_pci_devid_t){PCI_VENDOR_ID_INTEL,   PCI_DEVICE_ID_INTEL_82371FB_0})

typedef char byte;

typedef struct ide_pci_devid_t {
        int one, two;
} ide_pci_devid_t;

typedef struct ide_hwif_t {
        int whatever;
} ide_hwif_t;

typedef struct ide_pci_enablebit_s {
    byte        reg;    /* byte pci reg holding the enable-bit */
        byte    mask;   /* mask to isolate the enable-bit */
        byte    val;    /* value of masked reg when "enabled" */
} ide_pci_enablebit_t;

typedef struct ide_pci_device_s {
        ide_pci_devid_t         devid;
        const char              *name;
        void                    (*init_hwif)(ide_hwif_t *hwif);
        ide_pci_enablebit_t     enablebits[2];
        byte                    bootable;
        unsigned int            extra;
} ide_pci_device_t;

static ide_pci_device_t ide_pci_chipsets[] = {

     // HERE is where it says 'non-const initializer
        {DEVID_PIIXa,   "PIIX",         NULL,           {{0x41,0x80,0x80}, {0x43,0x80,0x80}},   ON_BOARD,       0 },

};
```

How can I still use the value of the `#define` while minimally altering the structure of the source to build with a C99 compiler?

Comment: Any chance you can show the error message **verbatim** (i.e. the *exact* text of the error, including the context in which it refers, variables, constants, and all)?

Comment: http://ideone.com/HTr4xc

Comment: I think it doesn't like the cast, which in this case is unnecessary for what you're doing.  Take out `(ide_pci_devid_t)` and the extra set of parens in the right-hand side of the macro and see if it works.  (I'm not positive, or I'd make this an answer; I'll bump it to an answer if that works.)

Comment: We have liftoff! Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is a 'C89 struct literal initializer syntax'; that is a C99 feature.

Comment: It looks like assigning to a struct variable a value in braces is called a struct initializer in C89 as well.  But the bit with the cast is something new in C99 called a [compound literal](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404).  When used to initialize a struct, they're the same as the braces without a cast, but you can do things with them like pass them as arguments to functions that take structs (as opposed to pointers to structs) as formal arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the cast in:

```
#define DEVID_PIIXa     ((ide_pci_devid_t){PCI_VENDOR_ID_INTEL,   PCI_DEVICE_ID_INTEL_82371FB_0})
```

Your compiler thinks that makes it non-constant.  Since where you're using the initializer is initializing a nested `ide_pci_devid_t` struct, you don't need the cast.  Changing that define to:

```
#define DEVID_PIIXa     {PCI_VENDOR_ID_INTEL,   PCI_DEVICE_ID_INTEL_82371FB_0}
```

will fix it.

(Lifted to an answer from the comment discussion.)